Flutter : WillpopScope / PopScope is not working in appBar back button (targeting Android 14+)
I created one screen DashBoard, in that I set bottom navigation and set other screen that all working but i need to add functionality, when user press back button than if other tab selected then it navigates to first tab other wise open Alert Dialog for asking question like "Are you sure you want to exit the app?".
I have implement using Will Pop scope set in Dash board screen.This is my code.
class DashBoardView extends GetWidget<DashBoardController> {
  const DashBoardView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MySize().init(context);
    getStatusBarColor(color: AppColor.whiteF9F9F9);
    return WillPopScope(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Obx(() => controller.pages[controller.currentIndex.value]),
          bottomNavigationBar: customBottomNavigation(),
        ),
        onWillPop: () {
          if (controller.currentIndex.value == 0) {
            AppDialog.appAlertDialog(
                context: context,
                description: "Are you sure you want to exit\nfrom the app? ",
                question: 'Exit app',
                questionTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: AppColor.grey, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                onTap: () {
                  Get.put(SocketController()).disconnectFromSocket();
                  exit(0);
                });
          } else {
            controller.currentIndex.value = 0;
            controller.update();
          }
          return Future.value(false);
        });
  }
}

But it is not working in Android 14+ version, I have also replace the Will pop scope to PopScope as per latest Update but it still not working.
If Anyone face this issue so please give me suggestion about this functionality in android 14+ version.

does it work on oldest version?

Can you try without getWidget

No, I have used the Get Widget.

try the back button interceptor, its more reliable - https://youtu.be/rShYGZoCFxs

WillPopScope is deprecated, so it is better to use PopScope.
return SafeArea(child: PopScope(
  canPop: false,
  onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async{
    if(didPop)
    {
      return;
    }
    if (controller.currentIndex.value == 0) {
        AppDialog.appAlertDialog(
            context: context,
            description: "Are you sure you want to exit\nfrom the app? ",
            question: 'Exit app',
            questionTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: AppColor.grey, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
            onTap: () {
              Get.put(SocketController()).disconnectFromSocket();
              exit(0);
            });
      } else {
        controller.currentIndex.value = 0;
        controller.update();
      }
      return Future.value(false);
    }
  },
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Container(
      child: Center(
        child: TextButton(onPressed: (){
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }, child: const Text('Back')),
      ),
    ),
  ),
));


Try this-
retrun WillPopScope(
     onWillPop: exitPopup,
     ..... );

Future<bool> exitPopup() async {
        return await showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                content: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(3.0),
                      // bottomRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(6.0),
                      // bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  height: 40,
                  child: Text(
                    "Alert!",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: BrandColors.kRed, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                actions: [
                  Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                      child: Text(
                        "Do you want to exit the application?",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      )),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(width: 5),
                      Expanded(
                        child: OutlinedButton(
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all(BrandColors.brandColor),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                          child: const Text('Cancel',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 5),
                      Expanded(
                        child: OutlinedButton(
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                              // backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                              //     Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2)),
                              ),
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                          child: const Text('Yes',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 5),
                    ],
                  ),
                  // SizedBox(height: 20),
                ],
              ),
            ) ??
            false;
      }


You can try this is better to use PopScope.
 _exitApp() async {
if (await webViewController!.canGoBack()) {
  webViewController!.goBack();
} else {
  SystemNavigator.pop();
}}


PopScope(
  canPop: false,
  onPopInvoked: (_) {
    _exitApp();
  },
  child: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Platform.isAndroid ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          InAppWebView(
            key: _webViewKey,

            /// show Web url with login user
            initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
              url: Uri.parse(
                // "Try to your Url"
            ),
            ),


This problem can be resolved by calling maybePop, instead of directly popping the context.
Navigator.maybePop(context)

This ensures that the Navigator handles the pop action correctly, considering any potential nested navigators. Or simply allow the AppBar to include the default back button.

I had a pager in a screen and I wanted to handle onBackPress in my screen especially the native back and I had the same problem as yours. When I search through many issues I found out that it is related to Google's new awesome android 13 onbackpress dispatcher development.
I have tried to use PopScope and WillPopScope with android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback=”false” and android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback=”true” with all possible combination. Non of them worked for me.
Solution:
I have used this flutter library
back_button_interceptor: ^7.0.3 https://pub.dev/packages/back_button_interceptor
You must add this to android manifest file in your project.(Put it under <activity tag)
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
....
<application
    .....
    <activity
        ...
        android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="false"
        ...

then add backpress interceptor init state of your widget and remove on dispose. In my case, I had a pager, onbackpress dispatcher should only be handled if it is not first page(page index > 0). And if user clicked backpress on page 12, it should navigate back to page 10. This example is a showcase of its usage, you can easily modify based on your needs. You can do what event you want inside _backButtonInterceptor.
class _OnboardingViewState extends State<OnboardingView> {
  final PageController _pageController = PageController();
  int _currentPage = 0;
  final OnboardingState _onboardingState = OnboardingState();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    BackButtonInterceptor.add(_backButtonInterceptor);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    BackButtonInterceptor.remove(_backButtonInterceptor);
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  bool _backButtonInterceptor(bool stopDefaultButtonEvent, RouteInfo info) {
    if (_currentPage > 0) {
      if (_currentPage == 12) {
        // If on GreatJobScreen, navigate back to DietSelectionScreen (page 10)
        _pageController.jumpToPage(10);
      } else {
        _pageController.previousPage(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        );
      }
      return true; // This stops the default back button behavior
    }
    return false; // Allow the default behavior if we're on the first page
  }
  ...

You will see that native back will start to work as expected.
